# localStorage.removeItem() doesn't work to remove array item

Tags: javascript

This morning I posted and @Victor solved my problem, but now I have another problem and I haven't been able to solve it since noon.

Link: [Show the element saved in localStorage when reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71842768/show-the-element-saved-in-localstorage-when-reload-the-page)

I improved the code by adding the add and remove button. The add add button worked but the remove button doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

```
<ul id="gfg">
        <li>Computer Network</li>
        <li>Data Structures using C</li>
</ul>

    <input type="text" id="text1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="test()" value="add"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="remove()" value="remove"></input>

function getStorageItems() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('items');
    return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
}

function saveStorageItem(text) {
    var array = getStorageItems() || [];
    array.push(text);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(array));
}

function addItem(text, save) {
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById('gfg').appendChild(node);

    if (save !== false)
        saveStorageItem(text);
}

function test() {
    a = document.getElementById('texto1').value;
    addItem(a);
}

function remove() {
    a = document.getElementById('texto1').value;
    localStorage.removeItem(a);
}

function loadFromStorage() {
    var array = getStorageItems();
    if (array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            addItem(array[i], false);
    }
}

loadFromStorage();
```

I want to do this:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVOYf.png

Comment: You are trying to remove a VALUE in localStorage, but items in localStorage have KEYS associated with them when they get added (you used the key "`items`"), so you have to remove that.

Comment: but using items i will remove all items, and i just need remove just a specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process of "adding an item" here involves:

- Getting the array from storage
- Adding the new "item" to the array
- Writing the new array to storage

As demonstrated in your code:

```
var array = getStorageItems() || [];
array.push(text);
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(array));
```

So the process of "*removing* an item" here would reasonably involve:

- Getting the array from storage
- Removing the specified "item" from the array
- Writing the new array to storage

Which, assuming your array elements are strings, would look something like:

```
var a = document.getElementById('texto1').value;
var array = getStorageItems() || [];
array = array.filter(function (element) {
  return element !== a;
});
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(array));
```

If, on the other hand, what you really want is to *remove the item* from local storage entirely, you'd just remove it by its name exactly like you added it by its name:

```
localStorage.removeItem('items');
```

(Part of your confusion here probably comes from terminology.  You're "adding an item" to local storage, and the "item" you're adding is a "list of items" in your code.  Local storage itself already uses the term "item", so call your data something different.  Meaningful names make code much easier to understand.)

Comment: ty man! But this function doesn't work here. Or idk how to use. im beginner in js,

Comment: update: worked! I used !==